# injecting Mocks through a chain of dependency classes using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mockito

Hi i have implemented a series of classes that use dagger 2 Injection to inject it dependencies for each class and i am trying to mock these to run my unit tests but it fails to initialise the dependencies found from the lower tier of classes that have dependencies.

This works fine in real enviornment but not for testing

I tried marking all the dependencies as either Spy or Mock but it only seems to inject the mocks on the first layer of my class that gets invoked. Below are three classes marked ExampleOne,Two,Three, followed by the test class.

ExampleOne has a method that calls another method from ExampleTwo, that then finally calls another from ExampleThree.

Only ExampleTwo gets the mock/spy injected fine but not ExampleThree.

```
public class ExampleOne{

    @Inject
    ExampleTwo exampleTwo;

    //implementations below

    public void doSomethingOne(){
        exampleTwo.doSomethingTwo;
    }
}


public class ExampleTwo{

    @Inject
    ExampleThree exampleThree

    public void doSomethingTwo(){
        exampleThree.doPrintHello();
    }
}

public class ExampleThree{

    public void doPrintHello(){
        Log.d("Print","Hello")
    }
}
```

Below is my test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestExamples(){

    @InjectMocks
    ExampleOne exampleOne

    @Spy
    ExampleTwo exampleTwo = new ExampleTwo();

    @Spy
    ExampleThree exampleThree = new ExampleThree();

    @Test
    void test(){

        exampleOne.doSomethingOne();

        //some testing code here
    }

}
```

Comment: Just my opinion here but you should practice explicit dependency principle either via constructor or method. Next, unit tests should be isolated. You should have no need to access implementation concerns in this case. Your classes a tightly coupled to implementation concerns and not abstractions which is a code smell.

Comment: `ExampleOne` has one dependency and if that dependency is not able to be mocked/stubbed/faked without side effects then there is a problem with the design of the target class.

Comment: So the design is flawed? This is using delegator pattern which is a common design pattern. Still, there will be other cases where you invoke two or 3 classes that need there dependencies created. this solution works perfectly fine in production

Comment: Just because it works in production does not make it the best solution or that design is *not* flawed. You would just be incurring technical debt.

Comment: While pointing out the one dependency I was referring to dependencies at the same level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practice explicit dependency principle either via constructor injection or method injection. Next, unit tests should be isolated. You should have no need to access implementation concerns in this case. Your classes are tightly coupled to implementation concerns and not abstractions which is a code smell.

```
public class ExampleOne {    
    ExampleTwo exampleTwo;

    @Inject    
    public ExampleOne(ExampleTwo exampleTwo) {
        this.exampleTwo = exampleTwo;
    }

    //implementations below

    public void doSomethingOne(){
        exampleTwo.doSomethingTwo();
    }
}

public interface ExampleTwo {
    void doSomethingTwo();
}

public class ConcreteExampleTwo implements ExampleTwo {
    private ExampleThree exampleThree;

    @Inject    
    public ConcreteExampleTwo(ExampleThree exampleThree) {
        this.exampleThree = exampleThree;
    }

    public void doSomethingTwo(){
        exampleThree.doPrintHello();
    }
}

public interface ExampleThree {
    void doPrintHello();
}

//...code removed for brevity
```

`ExampleOne` has one dependency at that level and if that dependencies are not able to be mocked/stubbed/faked without side effects then there is a problem with the design of the target class.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestExamples(){

    @Mock
    ExampleTwo exampleTwo;

    @InjectMocks
    ExampleOne exampleOne

    @Test
    void test(){

        exampleOne.doSomethingOne();

        verify(exampleTwo).doSomethingTwo();
    }    
}
```

With the above suggested changes `ExampleOne` can be tested in isolation without any knock on effects.

The concrete implementation of `ExampleTwo` can also be tested in isolation as well.

Comment: On full production code , for each class i have a empty constructor with the Inject marked on it to auto wire it and works in production.  Should i be removing the @Inject ExampleTwo and instead add that to the ExampleOne's Constructor as do the same to any proceeding classes?

Comment: @jonney note the constructors in my example are not empty. Also that my classes depend on abstractions and not concretions.

Comment: @jonney I would also suggest you read up on SOLID principles.

Comment: Ok thanks let me give this a go. i think the main fix here is using ExampleThree as a param for the constructor, i will also read up on SOLID principles

Comment: OK it fixed my issue. Thanks. Am just wondering about this approach though. Say if ExampleOne had multiple dependencies. Wont it look "ugly adding all those dependencies inside the constructor instead of us doing Inject exampleTwo inject exampleThree inject exampleFour instead of inject/constructor(exampleTwo, Three, Four...) ?

Comment: There could be scenarios where exampleOne will only need two out of 4 dependencies for void fun one() and the other two dependencies for void fun two()

Comment: @jonney nothing wrong with having multiple dependencies. It does however sometimes indicate that the dependent class may be doing too many things and may be violating single responsibility principle (read separation of concerns). Besides that, the DI container will be the one responsible to doing the injections and it has no opinion about having to inject multiple dependencies.

Comment: Yes so far none of my classes in prod uses more then 3/4 dependencies so it may be ok. At least with this approach it makes unit test easier as i can inject the dependencies mock that a test class object needs

Comment: @jonney when you research SOLID you see how it makes code design and maintenance better IMO.